# scala hashmap get string value returns some()

Tags: scala, hashmap

```
val vJsonLoc = new HashMap[String, String]();    
def getPrevJson(s:String) = vJsonLoc.get(s)
val previousFile = getPrevJson(s"/${site.toLowerCase}/$languagePath/$channel/v$v/$segment")
```

this returns

```
Some(/Users/abc/git/abc-c2c/)
```

on trying to append string `previousFile + "/" + index + ".json"`

the result is `Some(/Users/abc/git/abc-c2c/)/0.json` when the desired result is `/Users/abc/git/abc-c2c/0.json`

Guess this is some concept of Option that have not understood. New to scala.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, you're getting back an `Option` type, and not a direct reference to the `String` contained in your data structure.  This is a very standard Scala practice, allowing you to better handle cases where an expected value might not be present in your data structure.

For example, in Java, this type of method typically returns the value if it exists and `null` if it doesn't.  This means, however, subsequent code could be operating on the `null` value and thus you'd need further protection against exceptions.

In Scala, you're getting a reference to an object which may, or may not, have the value you expect.  This is the `Option` type, and can be either `Some` (in which case the reference is accessible) or `None` (in which case you have several options for handling it).

Consider your code:

```
val vJsonLoc = new HashMap[String, String]();    
def getPrevJson(s:String) = vJsonLoc.get(s)
val previousFile = getPrevJson(s"/${site.toLowerCase}/$languagePath/$channel/v$v/$segment")
```

If the `HashMap` returned `String`, your `previousFile` reference could point to either a `null` value or to a `String` value.  You'd need to protect against a potential exception (regular practice in Java).

But in Scala, `get` is returning an `Option` type, which can be handled in a number of ways:

```
val previousFile = getPrevJson("your_string").getOrElse("")
//or
val previousFile = getPrevJson("your_string") match {
    case Some(ref) => ref
    case None => ""
}
```

The resulting reference `previousFile` will point to a String value: either the expected value ("get") or the empty string ("OrElse").

Answer (score 0):

Scala `Map` on `get` returns `Option`. Use `vJsonLoc(s)` instead of `vJsonLoc.get(s)`

Comment: Note that `vJsonLoc(s)` is unsafe, i.e. partial - it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the looked-up key does not exist in the map. `scala> Map(1 -> 100)(5)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 5`

Comment: Agree. @bedwyr  description and solution is more generic